# Divi - How to vertically align stacked images in columns, within in a section

Tags: html, css, divi

Guys I cannot for the life of me figure out how to vertically align the images in this section.
[See the Divi builder screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbXC2.png)

I've aligned them with an aspect ratio that would make them the same height but unfortunately the 20px padding in between the right images is making them protrude.
This is happening on all of my sections!

[The uneven images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkrfa.jpg)

Please help!! I cant find a solution that works anywhere! :/

Website URL: [www.tessa-jane.com](https://www.tessa-jane.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `align-items: flex-end;` on flexbox.

```css
@media (min-width: 981px)
.et_pb_row.et_pb_equal_columns, .et_pb_row_inner.et_pb_equal_columns, .et_pb_section.et_pb_equal_columns>.et_pb_row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    direction: ltr;
    align-items: flex-end;

}
```

But keep in mind the main issue is the height of the image needs to be increased. When you align the bottom (the problem in the picture) the top becomes offset. I would suggest increasing the height of the image also. But this at least fixes the bottom portion.

Comment: Hi Kameron, 

Thank you for your reply and help! 
I did this and it worked and I see what you're saying about the top gap now. 

I ended up chucking the images in Illustrator and mimicking the padding with guides so I could get the exact aspect ratio right and now its perfect!  
Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

I just review your website you have to add **height: 100%** in few elements. There are 2 options to resolve your issue.

**Option 1:** Add **Height 100% Class** or **Inline CSS** in below mentioned elements.

[image]

**Option: 2** Add below CSS in style.css file.

```
.et_pb_image {
  height: 100%;
}
.et_pb_image_wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
.et_pb_image_wrap img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

I hope it'll resolve your issue, Thank You